# Pi-3 virtual box

Tags: pi-3

I have raspberry pi 3b with kali linux, i want to know that is it save to install metasploitable 2 in virtual box in raspberry pi 3b.
Will my raspberry pi be able to handle it because it have only 1 gb of ram

This is my raspberry Pi specs

Quad Core 1.2GHz Broadcom BCM2837 64bit CPU
1GB RAM
BCM43438 wireless LAN and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) on board
100 Base Ethernet
40-pin extended GPIO
4 USB 2 ports
4 Pole stereo output and composite video port
Full size HDMI
CSI camera port for connecting a Raspberry Pi camera
DSI display port for connecting a Raspberry Pi touchscreen display
Micro SD port for loading your operating system and storing data
Upgraded switched Micro USB power source up to 2.5A

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @kwasmich: Perhaps because VirtualBox is x86 only and it is not even possible.

Answer (score 2):

Programs must be compiled for the processor they are running on. **VirtualBox** is running on intel processors. But all Raspberry Pis have an ARM processor that isn't compatible with an intel processor like processors from AMD. So **VirtualBox** will never run on a Raspberry Pi. You cannot use it to run **metasploitable** as guest on it.